# Redirection to a another page asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing a problem, that occurs when I want to redirect the user after the create page, to another page that is not the index page.

I have tried to create another view in the Client folder and then replace "index" by "success" the name of the new page for example.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Client client)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Clients.Add(client);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); // Here is the problem

    }
}
```

I also try `Redirect("~/Client/Success")` but it doesn't work also.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work :

```
return RedirectToAction("Success","Client");
```

where `Success` is your `action name` and `Client` is your `controller name`

if you want to redirect to Success action in same controller then :

```
return RedirectToAction("Success");
```

Your action should look like this in ClientController :

```
public ActionResult Success()
{
  return View();
}
```

You are using :

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

this will redirect you to `Index` `actionresult` in same `controller`.

Comment: Yes I've just tried now but doesn't work, the resource cannot be found error

Comment: just make a view inside Client folder name it Success

Comment: I've written it with success but I think my problem is that I don't put the method success in my CLientcontroller is that the reason of my error ?

Comment: yes write this code in clientcontroller....  public ActionResult Success(){ return View(); }

Comment: Yes It is ok ! I've totally forgotten the controller Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create not only view named "Success" (actually that isn't required at all), but an **action** named "Success" in your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Client client)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.Clients.Add(client);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Success");
    }
    return View(); //Looks like you've missed this line because it shouldn't have compiled if result isn't returned in all code branches.
}

public ActionResult Success(Client client)
{
    //...
    return View();//By default it will use name of the Action ("Success") as view name. You can specify different View if you need though.
}
```

But **I wouldn't say it's a good idea to use redirect just to show the success result**. You better create the Success view in the Client folder as you've done already (assuming your controller is named "ClientController") and then return View result instead of Redirect:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Client client)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Clients.Add(client);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View("Success");
    }
    return View(); //Looks like you've missed this line because it shouldn't have compiled if result isn't returned in all code branches.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the overloads for that method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx).  You're not redirecting to a *URL*, you're redirecting to an *action*.  So this will redirect to the `Index` action on the current controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Or this will redirect to the `Success` action on the `Client` controller:

```
return RedirectToAction("Success", "Client");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a Ajax resquest like that :

```
 $('#myButton').click(function () {
            var url = '/MyControllerName/MyPage';
            var $Param = $('#SomeParam').val();     
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: {
                   Param: $Param             
                }
            })
```